# zk framework frequent calls server side push/zkau?dtid

Tags: zk, server-push

I am seeing lots of these requests

```
POST /zkau?dtid=
```

Anyway to reduce them? I guess these are the requests to keep the data in sync between the `browser` and `server`.

I am seeing these requests for each session repeated almost `@ 1 sec.`

Comment: Which server-push method are you using? Which version of ZK are you using? Community Edition?

Comment: 6.5.4, Enterprise edition, Extending SelectorComposer;Using java.util.Timer to update the data at some interval.

Comment: Have 'desktop.enableServerPush(true)' to do server push. Concerned about the performance when the simultaneous user sessions grow.

Comment: Looks like desktop.enableServerPush(true) creates these requests.